# Eclipse Plugin for counting lines of code (Eclipse Juno)

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I've recently been looking for a plugin to count LOC in a project and it seems as though everything works with indigo and before, is there anything that supports Eclipse Juno that counts LOC in a project.

Comment: Did the Sonar plugin work for you Damien?  It doesn't seem to show up in eclipse for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot is surely the SonarQube plugin for eclipse.
You'll have LOC and many other metrics thanks to it.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse